# the_content suddenly not displaying content when using page or post custom template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I had to fall back to an earlier version of the site. It went right back to working as intended. I updated the woocommerce plug-in. All still worked. Suspect the Jetpack plug-in causing the trouble but can't prove it. (I deactivated it when troubleshooting but that didn't fix problem.) I just got email from GoDaddy saying they had detected the old version of Jetpack is causing a fatal error. I haven't seen an error yet but I believe them. Deactivated it and will probably uninstall it if I can use other plug-ins for the same features.

As I work to restore the posts I added in the last couple days, I'll make note if anything stops working and will report it here in case anyone else ever hits the same problem. TY.

https://fromstrawintogold.com/photo-album-index/warping-a-loom-front-to-back-ftb/

---

the_content and the_date in post and page template files not working

All was well. Custom page and post template worked as intended on WordPress site for months. Only used these custom templates for photo albums and blog. (Using child theme of Storefront theme. All store related pages use WooCommerce templates, unaltered.)

Suddenly, yesterday, custom page and post templates stopped displaying the content and the date. I had added products to WooCommerce but no changes to code. Added demo products in past with no problem.

When I saw the problem, I turned all plug-ins off, including WooCommerce - malfunction continues. I just can't figure out why code that worked suddenly refused to pick up the_content and date, especially when I had made no changes to the templates that morning.

- Turned off plug-ins.
- Looked at functions.php to see if anything affected the_content. Didn't see anything and custom functions file is the same as when the_content worked.
- Pulled up pages and posts in Chrome - no errors detected, though it doesn't show the_content being called.

If I must, I'll restore a version of the site from days ago to see if the problem clears up but would rather avoid that if possible.

From picture album post template:

```
<div class="hundred">
    <div class="sixty-o-pic">
        <div class="secondborder">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="forty-o-pic">
        <div class="hundred-o-comment">
        <h1> <?php the_title() ; ?> </h1>
        <h2> <?php echo get_post(get_post_thumbnail_id())->post_excerpt; ?> 
        </h2>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <hr />
        <div class="mininavbox">
            <!-- buttons -->
            <div class="miniholder">
                <?php echo previous_post_link('<strong>%link</strong>','<img src="https://fromstrawintogold.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/arrow-left-58x58.png">', TRUE); ?>
            </div>
        <?php if( in_category('52') ) : ?>
        <div class="miniholdercenter">
            <a class="one" href="https://fromstrawintogold.com/photo-album-index/around-the-ranch/"><img src="https://fromstrawintogold.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/arrowcircle-58x58.png" alt="return to album index" align="middle"></a>
        </div>
    <?php elseif( in_category('53') ) : ?>
        <div class="miniholdercenter">
            <a class="one" href="https://fromstrawintogold.com/photo-album-index/warping-a-loom-front-to-back-ftb/"><img src="https://fromstrawintogold.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/arrowcircle-58x58.png" alt="return to album index" align="middle" margin="auto"></a>
        </div>
    <?php elseif( in_category('54') ) : ?>
        <div class="miniholdercenter">
            <a class="one" href="https://fromstrawintogold.com/photo-album-index/sunrise-blanket/"><img src="https://fromstrawintogold.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/arrowcircle-58x58.png" alt="return to album index" align="middle" margin="auto"></a>                                                                              
        </div>
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="navholdercenter">
            <a class="one" href=" https://fromstrawintogold.com/photo-album-index/">Photo Albums</a>
        </div>
    <?php endif ; ?>
    <div class="miniholder">
        <?php echo next_post_link('<strong>%link</strong>','<img src="https://fromstrawintogold.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/arrow-right-58x58.png">', TRUE); ?> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="hundred-o-comment">
    <?php if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) { 
comments_template(); } ?>
</div>
```

Expect content and date to show as they did right up till yesterday morning. Instead, they don't. I'm baffled.

Comment: https://fromstrawintogold.com/photo-album/sunrise-blanket/warp-yarns/

I removed affected pages/posts from menu for now. If want to visit example affected post, link above is to a photo album page. There should be content under "Step 2"

Comment: Have you checked the content is still there in the wordpress backend? Is there a custom or standard loop around the sample code you posted?

Comment: The content does still exist. I choose this as a post template when creating the post, so it's automatically part of the loop.

Comment: Very strange, can you access $post and to a print_r() or var_dump() on it to see if there is any post object?

Comment: I will try. I agree it's strange.

Comment: Unrelated, but `<?php the_content() ?>` shouldn't be wrapped in `<p>` tags - it generates it's own!

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the entire contents of your album post template file? What you have provided so far isn't enough to see what's going on so that might help.

Comment: Will add more of the code. I didn't want to overdo it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a similar issue with my client's wordpress site also hosted on GoDaddy.  "the_content" just recently stopped working.  I have reviewed the code, and everything seems to be in line with the information I have found regarding "the_content" and it's use.  I was upgraded to Gutenberg, but that was a while ago and it was working.  Now it's using wp version 5.2.2, and I have no idea why it's suddenly stopped working.  I can the new "block" editor's content to post, but not via the_content.  Really strange.

I hate to say it, but I suspect it has something to do with GoDaddy's "Managed Wordpress" hosting service which autoupdates wordpress core and god knows what else.  It also has sucuri's firewall added to the site via GoDaddy if that helps fill in some of the gaps on what else might be happening.

Comment: I've found it happens on a client's site, if a plugin fails on an update with an error 500. GoDaddy always says that's not their fault. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post(); 
    
    the_content();

endwhile;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).